# Escape backslash in net localgroup command

Tags: windows, escaping

Anyone know how to escape a command like this inside cmd.exe under Windows 7?

```
net localgroup "COMPANY\Administrators"
```

it returns:

```
The syntax of this command is:

NET LOCALGROUP [groupname [/COMMENT:"text"]] [/DOMAIN]
groupname {/ADD [/COMMENT:"text"] | /DELETE}  [/DOMAIN]
groupname name [...] {/ADD | /DELETE} [/DOMAIN]
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you have to **escape** that? What do you need to do?

Comment: The command above should list all users inside the group "COMPANY\Administrators", unfortunately as you see it returns an error because of the backslash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to escape domain name because `localgroup` command **can not** list all users of a given domain group.

`net localgroup` will list all users (both local or from domain) that belong to a given local group (a group that exist on your computer). To get a list of all groupnames registered on your domain controller you should use:

```
net group /domain
```

Then to see users from one group (in this example a fake group named `RD`):

```
net group RD /domain
```

With *standard* command line tools you cannot:

- List all users that belongs to a group *named* Administrators (note that a group named Administrators in your computer *may* not even exist in another computer).
- List all domain users with administration privileges in some computer on the domain (you can list only local ones).

See [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/49405/command-line-to-list-users-in-a-windows-active-directory-group) for more options (with external addins).